# Considering that std::cout is an initialized object, why does visual studio 'not recognise its identifier' whilst setting a Watch in the debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cout

Considering that `std::cout` is an initialized object, why does visual studio *'not recognise its identifier'* whilst setting a Watch in the debugger?

How do I view this object in memory?

Setting both `std::cout` and `cout` as watch variables returns:

[identifier "std::cout" is undefined]

[identifier "cout" is undefined]

respectively.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Usage of std::cout\n";

    // breakpoint
    return 0;
}
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout on the topic of cout:

> These objects are guaranteed to be initialized during or before the
> first time an object of type `std::ios_base::Init` is constructed and
> are available for use in the constructors and destructors of static
> objects with ordered initialization (as long as `<iostream>` is included
> before the object is defined).

Comment: Did you link your program using the debug version of th c++ runtime library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a local reference to `std::cout` and add a watch for that. E.g.:

```
auto& mycout = std::cout;
```